# Same origin policy - Subdomains and Root Domain

Tags: same-origin-policy

I have a question regarding the `same-origin` policy.

My company has many subdomains and in one of them they would like an iframe with another subdomain inside of it and populate the form of the iframe.

I have read about the `document.domain` property and that I would need to set in on all three domains, however I can not easily test this due to each subdomain belonging to a different department. So here is my question:

Is this possible when the subdomains are both https, and the root domain is not? I looked at the examples on wikipedia, but that didn't help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Example:**

```
https://x.company.org
https://y.company.org
http://company.org
```

`x.company.org` will have a page with an iframe of y.company.org which has a form that we would like to auto populate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The things that define a domain in this context are protocol, port and domain so http://abc.com and https://abc.com are considered different domains by your browser (http vs https).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

https://x.company.org and https://y.company.org are also considered separate domains but they can both relax their domain setting to https://company.org and cross-communicate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#document.domain_property

There's another option available to you now as HTML5 is in all the major browsers.  Using the HTML5 postMessage you can communicate across domains, assuming the receiving domain wants to accept the message and respond.

http://html5demos.com/postmessage2

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify your answer, when you said they can relax the domain setting to the root domain. Does the root domain have to also use the same protocol ?

Also, unfortunately we can not use the post message because most of our users are still using IE7 and IE8.

Comment: I understood your example to say that x.company.org would be hosting y.company.org in an iframe.  In that case, both pages should do docoument.domain="company.org" for this to work: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy#the-document-domain-exception

Comment: You don’t need CORS for subdomains.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#document.domain_property

Comment: 2023 - `document.domain` option is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain